# Converting from infix to postfix? Java calculator

Tags: java

I totally get that theres a ton of code online of this already, but I've looked at those and I really don't get what Im doing wrong. Im creating a calculator that converts an expression from infix to postfix, and then computes it. Im creating the class for it; the main is a gui, and was given. I've been stumped over this problem. The two problems are:

- For some reason my precedence of operators doesn't work, when the output comes, the operators are really just printed backwards, for example I put in 
  5+5/2, instead of giving me 5 5 2 /+ it gives me 5 5 2 +/
- the second problem Im having is that my numbers wont print just the operators, like the previous example instead of getting 5 5 2 /+, im getting just +/

Any help would be appreciated, Im really frustrated and really can't even think anymore. You know what I mean.

here is my evaluator code:

```
 import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Evaluator{
  private String infixExp;
  private char opPrec;
  private char op;


public Evaluator(String infixExp){
    this.infixExp = infixExp; // holds my infix expression inputted from gui
    this.opPrec = opPrec; // not being used
    this.op = op;
}
    private boolean isOperator(char op){ // not being used i dont think?
    return(op == '+' || op == '-' || op == '*' || op == '/'
    || op == '^' || op == '(' || op == ')' || op == '%'||  op == '=');
}
 // this is where I order the precedence
private int isLowerPrec(char op) {
    if (op == ('(') || op ==(')') || op ==('='))

    return 0;

    if (op ==('+') || op ==('-'))

    return 1;

    if (op == ('*') || op == ('/'))

    return 2;
    if (op == ('^')|| op ==('%') )

    return 3;
    else
        return -1;
} // end lowerPrecedence
/* converting the infix to postfix, must return expression as a String
   but numbers should be converted to doubles  */

public String Convert(){
    // must use stacks & queues 
    Stack <Character> exp = new Stack<Character>();
    Queue result = new LinkedList(); // not sure how to incorporate queue
    String postfix = "";
    int priority = 0;

    // going through infix expression
    for (int i = 0; i < infixExp.length(); i++){
     // expr(infixExp);
        op = infixExp.charAt(i);

        if(infixExp.length() == 0){
           continue;
        }

       // this is where I call my precedence
       // I know Im close but am missing something
        if(isLowerPrec(op) == -1){
           priority = -1; // pushing numbers onto stack
                if(exp.isEmpty() && priority == -1 ){
                postfix += exp.push(op);

             }
         }
         if(op == '+' || op == '-'){ // come first in stack
            priority = 1;
            isLowerPrec(op);
            if(priority == 1 && isLowerPrec(op) == 1 ){
                postfix += exp.push(op);

               }
           } 

             if(op == '*' || op == '/'){ // come second
                priority = 2;
                //isLowerPrec(op);

                if(priority == 2 && isLowerPrec(op) == 2 || exp.isEmpty()){
                      postfix += exp.push(op);
                     if(exp.peek() == '+' || exp.peek() == '-' ){
                     postfix += exp.push(op);

               }
            }   
        }
        if(op == '^'|| op ==('%')){ // come third
            priority = 3;
            isLowerPrec(op);
            if(priority == 3 && isLowerPrec(op) == 3){
                postfix += exp.push(op);

            }  


        }




       }
         // these must be deleted
        if(op == ')' || op == '(' || op == '='){ // delete
            priority = 4;
            isLowerPrec(op);
             if(priority == 4 && isLowerPrec(op) == 0){
                postfix += exp.push(op);
                 postfix += exp.pop();

            }                 
        }


            return postfix;
   }
 }
```

I didn't include the gui calculator code, just because it is pretty long.
I can if I must however, thanks for any help or advice you can give!

Comment: You should start by refactoring your code: Fix the formatting (e.g., indentations and linebreaks) and delete everything that is not used (including `priority` in `Convert`, since all you do with it is assign a value and then check whether it actually holds the assigned value). Not having clutter in your code helps finding out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Regarding your second problem:

The reason your code does not print the numbers is the conditional `exp.isEmpty()` in

```
if(exp.isEmpty() && priority == -1 ){
    postfix += exp.push(op);
```

that is, as soon as the first symbol is pushed onto `exp`, then no more numeric literals are read, since you only `pop` the stack when brackets are read.

#### Regarding your first problem:

I am not sure what your algorithm is supposed to be doing, but it looks to me like it adds each symbol it can find to the string `postfix`, so basically it is just copying the input string and not transforming it. Hence, the operators are always printed in the order they appear in the string and not in the desired order.

#### How you could approach the problem

I can't help you fixing your existing code directly, as it seems there is too much of the implementation missing. However, I might help you getting a different look at the problem.

Think about the expression as a tree with numeric literals as leaves and operators as nodes. For example, the expression `1 + 2 * (3 - 4) / 5` would be represented by the following tree:

[image]

Now, to print this tree in postfix form, you would print the left subtree in postfix form, then the right subtree in postfix form, then the value of the node itself. Step by step, we would print the tree as follows:

- **print** the leaf `1` (prints `"1"`)
- convert the subtree at `/`

  - convert the subtree at `*`

    - **print** the leaf `2`
    - convert the subtree at `-`

      - **print** the leaf `3`
      - **print** the leaf `4`
      - **print** operator `-`
    - **print** operator `*`
  - **print** leaf `5`
  - **print** operator `/`
- **print** operator `+`

So the printed postfix string is `1 2 3 4 - * 5 / +`

Luckily, such an expression tree is not that hard to implement:

```
public abstract class ExpressionTree {
    public abstract String postfixString();
}

public class ExpressionTreeNode extends ExpressionTree {
    final Operator operator;
    final ExpressionTree left, right;

    public ExpressionTreeNode(Operator operator, ExpressionTree left, ExpressionTree right) {
        this.operator = operator;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Node(%s, %s, %s)", operator.toString(), left.toString(), right.toString());
    }

    public String postfixString() {
        return String.format("%s %s %s", left.postfixString(), right.postfixString(), operator.toString());
    }
}

public class ExpressionTreeLeaf extends ExpressionTree {
    final int value;

    public ExpressionTreeLeaf(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Leaf(%d)", value);
    }

    public String postfixString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}

public enum Operator {
    ADDITION, SUBTRACTION, MULTIPLICATION, DIVISION, POWER, MODULO;

    public String toString() {
        switch (this) {
            case ADDITION:
                return "+";
            case SUBTRACTION:
                return "-";
            case MULTIPLICATION:
                return "*";
            case DIVISION:
                return "/";
            case POWER:
                return "^";
            case MODULO:
                return "%";
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown Operator");
        }
    }
}
```

And if we manually build this tree, we get the expected result:

```
System.out.println(
        new ExpressionTreeNode(
                Operator.ADDITION,
                new ExpressionTreeLeaf(1),
                new ExpressionTreeNode(
                        Operator.DIVISION,
                        new ExpressionTreeNode(
                                Operator.MULTIPLICATION,
                                new ExpressionTreeLeaf(2),
                                new ExpressionTreeNode(
                                        Operator.SUBTRACTION,
                                        new ExpressionTreeLeaf(3),
                                        new ExpressionTreeLeaf(4)
                                )
                        ),
                        new ExpressionTreeLeaf(5)
                )
        ).postfixString()
);
```

Now the problem of printing a postfix expression given a string is simplified to building an expression tree from the string. You can build this tree by

1. Discovering matching brackets and transforming the substring within the brackets to an expression tree. Hint: find the first closing bracket and then the last opening bracket in the substring ending at the closing bracket. See also `indexOf()` and `substring()` in `String`.
2. If there are no brackets, find the operators with highest precedence and create a subtree with these operators and whatever sub-expression is left and right of them.
3. Continue until you processed the operators with the lowest precedence
4. Numeric literals are transformed into a `new ExpressionTreeLeaf(number)`